# When should I NOT use mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I saw this comment.... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#93005

And began to wonder why this would be a bad idea.

Comment: Whenever you could use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bad idea for a couple reasons:

- First, it assumes that your inputs
  will always be going into the
  database and into the database alone.
  What if something is going to be used
  in HTML output? Or in an email? Or
  written to a file? Or lots of other
  things.. your filtering should always
  be context-sensitive.
- More importantly, it encourages
  sloppy use of GET, POST, etc because
  there's no indication that they've
  been filtered. If someone sees you
  use

  echo $_POST['name'];

  on a page, how would they know it's
  been filtered? Or even worse... are
  you sure it has been? What about that
  other app? You know, the one you were
  just handed? What would new developers do? Would they even know that filtering is important?

Comment: +1.  My rule is, sanitize for a given medium only immediately *before*  entering that medium.  So you sql-escape your strings only immediately before using them in a query, *not* at the HTTP->PHP transition, like the php.net comment in question suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you should never have to escape anything prior to using it in a query via use of PDO prepared statements. The underlying libraries will take care of escaping for you.

In practice, if you can't/won't use prepared statements, the escaping should be done only immediately prior to building the query string. Don't blindly go and remap the contents of the various superglobals (GET, POST, REQUEST, COOKIES) on the assumption that everything will be going into a DB. Think of the case where you have to validate the form data first, and some field(s) isn't filled in correctly. Now you have to unescape everything from "database mode", and re-escape into "html mode" to reinsert the good data back into the form again.

The same goes for htmlentities/htmlspecialchars. Don't do until you know you're outputting into HTML/XML. Once you go applying escaping/encoding/quoting everywhere, you'll run the risk of double-encoding stuff and end up with useless constructs like `&amp;quot;`

Answer (score 2):

On any data that is not going to be put into an SQL query. If you need to escape output, use htmlspecialchars() (or similar). The same holds true for database input; escape it only beforeit is going in.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from that particular comment on the site specifically for that code example, I think he's saying if magic_quotes is off and you're sure you'll only be using your code on a server with it off you can edit the code and remove the `if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())... etc`

In general though it's useless against data you include inside a query which you don't use quotes on - ie integers for ids, these need to be checked for type.

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql_real_escape_string when you want to escape a string to be included in a sql query that is going to a mysql database - anything outside of that scope would be a clear indication of 'when not to use' it :)

here's a verbose implementation:

```
function clean( $p )
{
  if( function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string') ) {
    if( function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') ) {
      if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $p = stripslashes( $p );
      }
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string( $p );
  } else {
    return $p;
  }
}
```